# PHP - MySQL- Get names from other tables with an id

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have a mysql database with multiple tables that describe playlists and users(each of these tables has an ID and Name for the playlist/user).

Now, i have one table "PlaySent" that has only IDs that point to one playlist and two users (a recipient and a sender).

My objective is to Select all records from this table (PlaySent) where i don't get these IDs but the names they represent.

I believe i have to use an INNER JOIN?

EDIT: I have made a sketch of the tables in question, so they can be in english
[image: the tables in question]

So again, i need a query that returns me all data from PlaylistSent where it doesn't show me the id, but the names of the playlist and the users in each row

Comment: Can you post a snippet that accurately re-creates the problem?

Comment: See... well, anything

Comment: Nothing much we can do to help when you give nothing.  Learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**

Your Query will look like this, you have not posted the exact name of the fields so i am just assuming.

```
SELECT pl.PlaylistName as playlist_name,sender.Username as sender_name,receiver.Username as receiver_name
FROM PlaylistSent AS ps
INNER JOIN Users AS sender
   ON ps.1stUserID=sender.id
INNER JOIN Users AS receiver
   ON ps.2ndUserID=receiver.id
INNER JOIN Playlist AS pl
   ON ps.PlaylistId=pl.id
```

---

**Off topic**

I would suggest you next time to:

1) include the exact database structure

2) include any SQL you tried and did not work and the output of the SQL

3) include a small sample of data

Also it would be helpfull for you to start by reading a book or a tutorial to learn the syntax and get a deeper understanding on the topic you try to learn

Comment: I respect the endeavour, but really, questions of this paucity are rarely worth the bother.